# Difference between iterator.getCurrentRow and vo.getCurrentRow in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am working in ADF. Most of time whenever I have to get current row programmatically, I used to write following code.

```
 DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();  
 DCIteratorBinding iterBind= (DCIteratorBinding)dcBindings.get("VO name");
 ViewObject vo = iterBind.getViewObject();
 Row r = vo.getCurrentRow();
 or
 Row r = iterBind.getCurrentRow();
```

I don't understand the difference.

Sometimes, vo.getCurrentRow() throws nullPointerException but iterBind.getCurrentRow() works fine.

I want to understand what can be the approach on it. Please suggest me that how internally it works.